# Posgres : perf decreased although server is better :(

Tags: vps, postgresql, ovh, pgbouncer

I've changed my VPS hosting for the better and saw a significative performance decrease.

Before :
`AMD 8 cores@2.8Ghz, 16 GB RAM, Ubuntu 14.04, Postgres 9.4, Pgbouncer 1.7, SSD 80Mb/s`

After:
`Haswell 4 cores@2.4Ghz, 24 GB RAM, Ubuntu 16.04, Postgres 9.6, Pgbouncer 1.7.2, SSD 180Mb/s`

My Application Monitoring Performance (NewRelic) shows 100% increase in SQL response time:
[image: NewRelic APM shows SQL explode from 100ms average to 250ms average]

The configuration files are the same (I use Ansible for automated deployment). I've benchmarked the network with `iPerf`, it's the same speed. I've ping both VPS, I've lost 2,5 ms with the new server (not the same datacenter, seems ok to me).

What tickles me is that server resources are not maxed out:

[image: Server performance monitoring shows everything is low on resource usage]

Last but not least, why so many idle connections? What setting am I missing to improve performance?

[image: Postgres dashboard]

## EDIT 1

Before:

- `bonnie++ -u postgres -d /tmp/ -s 4096M -r 1096` http://pastebin.com/mBi8UstP
- `stream` http://pastebin.com/xrLN9Q6s

After:

- `bonnie++ -u postgres -d /tmp/ -s 4096M -r 1096` 1. http://pastebin.com/hbTrZ8hT (during a regular day) 2. http://pastebin.com/h8PYQxiw (during sunday night)
- `stream` http://pastebin.com/fDm9aNDh

## EDIT 2

Before, ping:

```
root@vps170028:~# ping vps166893.ovh.net
PING vps166893.ovh.net (149.202.33.76) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=1 ttl=63 time=0.490 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=2 ttl=63 time=0.504 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=3 ttl=63 time=0.541 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=4 ttl=63 time=0.520 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=5 ttl=63 time=0.501 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=6 ttl=63 time=1.12 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=7 ttl=63 time=0.538 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=8 ttl=63 time=0.723 ms
64 bytes from 76.ip-149-202-33.eu (149.202.33.76): icmp_seq=9 ttl=63 time=0.488 ms
^C
--- vps166893.ovh.net ping statistics ---
9 packets transmitted, 9 received, 0% packet loss, time 7999ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.488/0.603/1.126/0.198 ms
```

After, ping:

```
root@vps170028:~# ping vps332984
PING vps332984.ovh.net (51.255.200.128) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=1 ttl=57 time=5.32 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=2 ttl=57 time=5.23 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=3 ttl=57 time=5.24 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=4 ttl=57 time=5.32 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=5 ttl=57 time=5.11 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=6 ttl=57 time=5.35 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=7 ttl=57 time=5.17 ms
64 bytes from 128.ip-51-255-200.eu (51.255.200.128): icmp_seq=8 ttl=57 time=5.46 ms
^C
--- vps332984.ovh.net ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7007ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 5.110/5.278/5.462/0.132 ms
```

## EDIT 3

Performance of the select queries on a table1 before and after, same throughput.

[image: Explosion of a particular query]

Comment: Maybe it's a typo in your post, but you need to define "better" in your situation... your issues are potentially related to the fact that before you had 8 cores@2.8Ghz, after you have 4 cores@2.4Ghz.

Comment: It's not due to the number of cores

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've migrated back to my initial server, which eliminates:

1. performance decrease due to server raw characteristics
2. performance decrease due to network latencies

The issue is purely due to one of, or an interaction between :

- Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
- Postgres 9.6.1
- pgbouncer 1.7.2

I'll probably ask a new question.